# Using global variables in Snakemake modules

Tags: snakemake

I’m trying to use an existing workflow (*A*, maintained by someone else) as part of a new one (*B*) by defining it as a module. The existing workflow uses global variables in its rules. When I execute *A*, everything works, but when the same rules are executed from *B*, I get errors like `NameError: The name 'PYTHON' is unknown in this context`. This happens at least with Snakemake 7.22.0 and 7.32.4. Please see below for a minimal example.

**A.Snakemake**

```
PYTHON = 'python' # Global variable defined here

rule all:
    shell: '{PYTHON} --version' # and used here
```

**B.Snakemake**

```
module A_wf:
    snakefile: "A.Snakefile"

use rule * from A_wf as A_*
```

Running `snakemake --snakefile A.Snakefile -c 1` works as expected. Running `snakemake --snakefile B.Snakefile -c 1 A_all` causes the error. Any suggestions or workarounds to solve this are appreciated.

Comment: Would using f-string syntax help? (it's not clear to me if that's going to resolve your ultimate use case) This would require changing shell directive to: `f'{PYTHON} --version'`

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev Curiously it does help. Modifying *A* in this way would certainly be easier than the other options I considered so far. I’ll mention this in the [bug report](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2499) I filed.

Comment: Right, this should work as a hack... one case where this might break (not sure if this is something that can occur in your scenario) is the case where the variables in the imported workflows should be replaced by something else...